# not able to read config file in php

Tags: php

My php project folder structure is like below.

```
MyProject
projadmin
repadmin
inc
   header.php
templates
index.php
config.php
```

In config.php file I have some configs.

```
<?php
return Array (    
    'title'         => 'Title',
    'message'       => 'Your message :',
    'warnTime'      => '10000',
    'redirTime'     => '11000',
    'keepAliveUrl'  => '',
    'redirUrl'      => 'http://intranet.domain.com/default.aspx',       
    'logoutUrl'     => 'http://intranet.domain.com/default.aspx'
);    
?>
```

Now in /inc/header.php file, I've the below code to access the config file. But not getting anything.

```
$res = require_once('../config.php');
//printing the one value
echo "<script>console.log('In header res[redirUrl] is: " . $res['redirUrl'] . "' );</script>";
```

Then in the console I'm getting empty value.
Please help me where I did mistake?

Comment: Try `require_once(__DIR__.'/../config.php')`

Comment: Still not getting any value.

Comment: How are you including the /inc/header.php file.  Is it being loaded but just showing blank values or is the `<script>console.log` not showing up at all?

Comment: It is loading and just showing blank value i.e. " In header res[redirUrl] is: " .

Comment: Just to debug, change it to `print_r($res,true)` which should show the full data from the array.

Comment: It is not printing anything in the console for print_r($res,true)